# Scrapy running from python script processes only start url

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I have written a Scrapy *CrawlSpider*.

```
class SiteCrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'site_crawler'

    def __init__(self, start_url, **kw):
        super(SiteCrawlerSpider, self).__init__(**kw)

        self.rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_start_url', follow=True),
        )
        self.start_urls = [start_url]
        self.allowed_domains = tldextract.extract(start_url).registered_domain

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        external_links = LinkExtractor(allow=(), deny=self.allowed_domains).extract_links(response)
        for link in external_links:
            i = FastcrawlerItem()
            i['pageurl'] = response.url
            i['ext_link'] = link.url
            i['ext_domain'] = tldextract.extract(link.url).registered_domain                
            yield i
```

Now I am trying to run this script from another Python script as follows:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log, signals
from scrapy_fastcrawler.spiders.site_crawler import SiteCrawlerSpider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

spider = SiteCrawlerSpider(start_url='http://www.health.com/')
settings = get_project_settings()
crawler = Crawler(settings)
crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run()
```

Problem: Everything runs fine, but the major issue here is that the script processes only the 'start_url' and stops. It does not crawl and move to other links found on the start url and no processing being done. I have also setup pipelines and the items from start_url are correctly being saved to the pipeline setup.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you override the default `parse_start_url` for a crawl spider, the method has to yield `Request`s for the spider to follow, otherwise it can't go anywhere.

You are not required to implement this method when subclassing `CrawlSpider`, and from the rest of your code, it looks like you really don't want to; try changing the method you have defined to something like `parse_page` (just don't call it `parse`).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just tried this. But it doesnt work and now since it is actually not parsing the start url, I am not even getting the items from the start url page.

Comment: Have you tried the code with the `parse_start_url`, but have that method also return Requests for the links the spider should follow?

Comment: That is the problem. I think I dont know how to do that. Could you post a trivial example?

Comment: the [scrapy docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/stable/topics/spiders.html#scrapy-spider) have examples showing how to return Requests from parse methods

Comment: Thanks. This all was a great help. Got it working finally.